# Is there currency in the Grid?

Tags: tron, economics

Is there currency in the Tron Universe?

I have seen both Tron movies and the animated TV show but I still have a few questions about the universe.

I see programs treat their functions like jobs. Do they get paid? o programs pay for their basic needs or is it given to them?

They buy energy, upgrades, and have to fix damaged vehicles so is there a currency on the grid? If so, is it ever explained what it is?

Comment: Whether or not canon says there is, economics 101 says there is.  Energy (from the first Tron movie) is wanted by everyone and in restricted supply.  This is the premise upon which economics of exchange are created.